# How are URLs mapped to Domino forms?

Tags: lotus-domino, url-mapping

I have an URL that points to a Lotus Domino database, for example:

http://domino853.example.com/db.nsf/wcms/BEC4D26AD7A56823C1257B4B003427A8?OpenDocument

How is that URL mapped to the Domino form?

My first thought was the UNID is looked up in the database, and that the rest depends on the `Form` item of that document. But that's not the case. The actual form that gets resolved is neither `wcms` (like in the URL), nor `document` (like in `document.Form`), but it is `wcms_createdoc`. So where could that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found it:

1. `wcms` is an alias for another view.
2. That view has `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)` as its *first sorted column*.
3. And, to select the proper form, it has a `Form Formula` set.

So this is how it all happens:

1. The view `wcms` is resolved. Since the URL continues after the view name, the rest of the URL is the key into that view.
2. The first document of the view that matches the key is selected. Obviously, for the `DocumentUniqueID` there can be only one document.
3. Since the view has the `Form Formula` set, it is evaluated and maps to the form `wcms_createdoc`.
4. This form is rendered.

References:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/

Comment: Everything about the key lookup does not matter - it just resolves Form formula in "wcms" view.

Comment: Yes, the Form formula overrides the saved Form item in the document.  I'm not sure, however, if it would override an actual stored form. (That's a document with a $Title and $Body field. It's a rarely-used feature.)  If none of these are present, then the default form for the database is used.  Also, I don't recall what happens if the view is specified as '0' in the URL... It might be the case that the default view is used and the Form formula in the default view could override.